# Azure Data Factory: How to implement change feed in data flow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am building a pipeline to move data from CosmosDB to Delta table. ADF supports change feed for CosmosDB by default ONLY IF I select `Container` as input in the source. Due to requirements I have to use `Query` as input and as a result I can't select change feed in the source. What's the alternative way to implement Change feed in data flow? I would like to be able to upsert (and possibly delete) records into the delta table.

Currently I am using the `Alter row` modifier and set Upsert to `true()` in the `alter row conditions` section. And this modifier is piped from the source data. Not sure if this is the correct implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> Due to requirements I have to use `Query` as input and as a result I can't select change feed in the source

Currently, the Change feed in only supported for container in ADF dataflow. You can raise a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) about it for the query.

AFAIK, the only way to achieve your requirement can be apply the dataflow transformations after the source(with container).

You can use the transformations like **Filter** and **Select** to do the job that your query going to do.

[image]

You can apply the combination of these based on your query and transform to your sink.